# Building increasingly long strings from an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am writing a PHP function that will take an array in the following format:

```
array(
    'one',
    'two',
    'three'
)
```

And echo the following strings:

```
one
one-two
one-two-three
```

I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried using a variable to store the previous one and then use it, but it only works for one:

```
$previous = null;
for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
    echo ($previous != null ? $route[$previous] . "-" : '') . $route[$i];
    $previous = $i;
}
```

Outputting:

```
one
two
two-three
```

That approach would probably be inefficient anyway, as this script should technically be able to handle any length of array.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you want to create all the possible associations or only add one string at each iteration?

Comment: Just one string at each iteration, I think currently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1, $length = count($array); $i <= $length; $i++) {
    echo join('-', array_slice($array, 0, $i)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three');

foreach (array_keys($arr) as $index) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if ($key <= $index) {
             $result[] = $val;
        }
    }
    echo implode('-', $result) . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing 0 != null, the problem comes from the comparing with only one =, try !==, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Another one:

```
$data = array('one','two','three');
$str = '';
$len = count($data);
for ($i=0; $i<$len;$i++){
$delim = ($i > 0) ? '-' : '';
$str .=     $delim . $data[$i];
echo $str .'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`array_shift()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) in order to extract the first element from the array. Then we can iterate over the values and append them to a string:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'one',
    'two',
    'three'
);

// Get the first element from the array (it will be removed from the array)
$string = array_shift($array);
echo $string."\n";

foreach ($array as $word) {
    $string = implode('-', array($string, $word));
    echo $string."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
one
one-two
one-two-three
```

[Demo in Codepad](http://codepad.org/p5gy0Hlp).

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = ['one','two','three'];

doSomething($arr);

function doSomething($arr) {
  foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
      $s = array_slice($arr,0,($key+1));
      echo implode('-',$s) . "<br>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using `array_slice` and `implode` function

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    echo implode("-",array_slice($arr, 0, $key+1))."<br/>";
}
```

o/p

```
one
one-two
one-two-three
```